# Modifying configuration at runtime in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, amazon-web-services

I am having the following problem. I have an ASP.NET (VB.NET) application that is trying to connect to Amazon Web services using the AWS .NET SDK, and in order to do that the user is entering their Access and secret key. I am then adding the key to configuration like so:

```
 Dim config As Configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~")
 Dim settings As KeyValueConfigurationCollection = config.AppSettings.Settings
 settings("AWSAccessKey").Value = AmazonAccessKeyText.Text
 settings("AWSSecretKey").Value = AmazonSecretKeyText.Text
 config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
 ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
```

While this successfully modifies the web.config file, it still throws an exception at runtime saying that it can't find the Access key. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I believe the web.config is only read once when the app starts, so even though you are modifying it, it is once the app is running, so the key doesn't exist in the web.config that the application is currently using (that it read at app start). Hope that makes sense. :) I'd recommend storing the information elsewhere - a db, or maybe just another text file?

Comment: Why are you trying to use the configuration file in this way?  The configuration file should be something that is already created, and if it has to be modified, its modified by the user and then uploaded.  Either that have your program generate the file for the user given the user's input, this does neither, this data leakage waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have as ASP.NET application that connects to the AWS on the clients behalf, if so storing the clients credentials locally might be the best idea from a security point of view.

You can either

1. Only store the credentials in memory in the session only when needed in something like a SecureString
2. Store them encrypted on the disk using any crypt apis.

The amazon sdk doesn't need the credentials stored in the app/web.config. If you look at something like **[AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_AWSClientFactory_CreateAmazonS3Client_7.htm)** , you will notice that you can pass them as parameters to this function

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it is better to keep your received in key in Application object? for example static.
It is much clearer and simpler and will not cause a recycle of application when web.config is modified

Comment: I am not sure I understand, (My 2nd week on .NET), can you give me an example?